# Can Asterisk play sounds over a Marantz sound system?

Tags: asterisk

We are running Asterisk 1.2 (working on an upgrade) and in another building have a [Morantz](http://us.marantz.com/us/Products/Pages/ProductDetails.aspx?CatId=AVReceivers&ProductId=NR1602) sound system that is connected to the same subnet as Asterisk.

Can I use Asterisk to play a wav file over the Morantz's speakers?

My idea is to use a Cisco Port Adapter to convert the digital line into analog and then plug the analog into the RCA ports of the Morantz.  (see my [question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/729180/how-to-convert-rj11-to-rca/729202?noredirect=1#729202) about the RJ11 to RCA conversion)  I've done this in a different building with a Viking ZPI-4 Paging Interface, and use a "5" tone to tell the interface that the incoming data is to be played over a certain speaker zone.  Asterisk already knows how to play a bell tone.  With the Viking setup, since I have an ip address on the Port Adapter for it, I originate a call from the port adapter and Asterisk basically calls up the Viking like it was a phone.

The problem with the other building is that I don't have a Viking PA system rigged with speakers.  Instead I have a Morantz.  (It's actually hooked to a Control4, but I'm trying to get rid of the Control4 since the rep who admins it is never available and doesn't service us well).  So I want to play the wav file over the speakers attached to the Morantz.

But I am wondering that since the Morantz has a network connection (I can access it's web-interface), can I just send the sound directly over the Morantz?

Any ideas in this regard are welcome.

Comment: what do you want to play? asterisk is a pbx not a music player.

Comment: @bersch, ye of little imagination...

Comment: @bersch - the wav file is a bell tone like in a school.

Comment: Well, we have that Morantz with wireless speakers.  It's hooked to a Control4, actually, but I can't work with the Control4 (I want to get rid of it, in fact), and want to work directly with the Marantz.  I just want to play the tones over the speakers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get line-level audio to it, of course.  If you want to send a wav (or mp3) over the network, then you have some digging to do.  Click the "download" tab on the Morantz page you linked to find the remote command set to control the receiver. The most direct option would have asterisk run a script to send the necessary commands to the receiver, generate the necessary audio, and turn off the receiver / put it back to whatever it was already doing.

Comment: I don't know how to get line-level audio to it.  That thread of mine at Super-User was basically about that.  I just have the LAN connections.  By "receiver" - are you referring to the RCA ports?  I am adding a few notes to my question.  By "remote command" you mean IR command, right?  That makes it difficult.

Comment: "AV Receiver"  Commands can be sent to it via a serial port or over the network -- much like an IR remote, but far less complicated; this is generally how a "home automation" system interfaces with it. To use RCA line-in, you'll need a sound card or some other network based device.

Comment: (or maybe a usb thumb drive with the sound file on it, then send the necessary commands to get the receiver to play it.)

Comment: Are you saying that the Marantz will let me send commands over the network?  I have the command listing from the site.  I'm still missing something though - *how* do I send the commands (thanks for your time!)?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect asterisk channel to asterisk-alsa(local audio card of server)

After that you can connect sound card output to audio-in "Analog L&R In 6 (including Front mini jack input)" at your system.

Comment: Can you expand on that a little?  I'm afraid I am not quite up to the level yet.  By `asterisk channel`, do you mean the channel being the assigned extension?  How do I assign a channel to a sound card?  (I'm sorry!)  "...in 6" - what is 6?

Comment: See http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+alsa.conf. That one in quote is part of device description.

Comment: So are you meaning that if I connect the Marantz's audio-in port to the Asterisk's box's sound card, I can play directly over the Marantz?

Comment: Yes. Audio card output have be compatible with audio-in(sure if you have cable). You will be able do upto 1 channel from asterisk to audio card. If you need more then 1, you probably need use second card(usb or other pci).

Comment: Also if you have optical output on your card(can be on top-end desktop boards or dedicated cards), you can use optical sound port for connect both devices. Optical cable can be extreamly long, but it also extreamly costly.

Comment: This is an interesting approach and I want to try it (you got my +1). So I am understanding from you that Asterisk `alsa` will let me send sound to the sound card using Asterisk.  It looks like I get one channel with Asterisk 1.2, so I can try it.  I'll do that and mark my answer as soon as I have test results.